# Oracle trigger multiple conditions in when clause

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to create a trigger that updates a column in a table when other columns are updated. but getting the following error while saving the trigger

`ORA-25000: invalid use of bind variable in trigger WHEN clause`

My trigger is as follows, I'm not sure what is wrong with the code.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  Employees_ARIU 
BEFORE  INSERT OR  UPDATE ON Employees 
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN ((nvl(:OLD.EMP_SAL,0) != nvl(:NEW.EMP_SAL,0)) OR (nvl(:OLD.SAL_LEVEL,0) != nvl(:NEW.SAL_LEVEL,0)))
BEGIN
        :NEW.LAST_UPDATED = SYSDATE
END;
```

Comment: The trigger WHEN clause does not use colon(:) for references to NEW and/or OLD. So instead of  *(nvl(:OLD.EMP_SAL,0)* just use *(nvl(OLD.EMP_SAL,0)*.  Oracle has a explanation for this, but I cannot think of it at the moment. Always seemed to me like a distinction without difference anyway. Also you need a semi-colon after sysdate.

Comment: When I remove colon(:), It is returning ORA-04079: invalid trigger specification `CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  Employees_ARIU 
BEFORE  INSERT OR  UPDATE ON Employees 
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN ((nvl(OLD.EMP_SAL,0) != nvl(NEW.EMP_SAL,0)) OR (nvl(OLD.SAL_LEVEL,0) != nvl(NEW.SAL_LEVEL,0)))
BEGIN
        NEW.LAST_UPDATED = SYSDATE;
END;`

Comment: Only remove it in the WHEN condition. Not in the execution section. So *when old.emp_sal* but *:new.last_update ...*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although `IF` is an alternative to `WHEN`, I'd say that it is better to use `WHEN` clause whenever possible because it is a

> SQL condition that must be satisfied for the database to fire the trigger

So, why would you even let the trigger fire and then conclude that *oh, OK, I don't want to do anything, after all*? Better not running it at all!

Yes, `WHEN` clause has its restrictions and you can't put *anything* you want in there, but - your case isn't one of those.

(more info in [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7004.htm), search for "WHEN clause").

So, for a sample table

```
SQL> create table employees
  2    (id           number,
  3     emp_sal      number,
  4     sal_level    number,
  5     last_updated date);

Table created.
```

trigger would looks like this:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger employees_ariu
  2    before insert or update on employees
  3    for each row
  4    when (   nvl(old.emp_sal, 0)   <> nvl(new.emp_sal, 0)
  5          or nvl(old.sal_level, 0) <> nvl(new.sal_level, 0)
  6         )
  7  begin
  8    :new.last_updated := sysdate;
  9  end;
 10  /

Trigger created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> insert into employees (id, emp_sal, sal_level) values (1, 100, 1);

1 row created.

SQL> select * from employees;

        ID    EMP_SAL  SAL_LEVEL LAST_UPDATED
---------- ---------- ---------- -------------------
         1        100          1 12.06.2021 12:14:17

SQL> update employees set sal_level = 2 where id = 1;

1 row updated.

SQL> select * from employees;

        ID    EMP_SAL  SAL_LEVEL LAST_UPDATED
---------- ---------- ---------- -------------------
         1        100          2 12.06.2021 12:14:33

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try updating your WHEN condition to IF statement along with few other changes -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Employees_ARIU 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON Employees
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
     IF ((nvl(:OLD.EMP_SAL,0) != nvl(:NEW.EMP_SAL,0)) OR (nvl(:OLD.SAL_LEVEL,0) != nvl(:NEW.SAL_LEVEL,0))) then
        :NEW.LAST_UPDATED := SYSDATE;
     END IF;
END;
/
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fef03f2f3a29c4f4d28bb3108c8eec85).